EnableRetryOnFailure() not working for "40001" Serialization
I'm working on a project based on Winforms, C# with Entity Framework, writing/reading data from a PostgreSQL database.
I'm going to have only a low number of clients (4/5) and low traffic, so I decided to use Serializable isolation level in order to make it easier to develop and safer, even if I'm going to lose some performance.
Now I'm trying to handle a "40001 Serialization" error, and I'm trying to put a retry logic in place, but I know that EF has a built-in retry logic, so I tried to use EnableRetryOnFailure(), but it seems it's not working properly.
I tried to add in my OnConfiguring method:
options.EnableRetryOnFailure(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), new List<string> { "40001" }))

But it seems that it's not retrying but is firing an exception every time.
Any idea or suggestion?
Thank you
This is my error message:

fail: 21/06/2024 15:45:29.512 RelationalEventId.CommandError[20102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
Failed executing DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[@p0='TEST CLIENT' (Nullable = false), @p1='OV24-00001' (Nullable = false)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO sales_orders (client_name, ov_number)
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
RETURNING id_sales_orders;

